# FFmpeg-PHP XDebug errors

Tags: php, xdebug, ffmpeg-php

I have recently downloaded the FFmpeg-PHP extension (extracted from ffmpeg-php53-win32-vc9-all.zip) for PHP and I have been using it alongside FFmpeg-0.5.2.1 to extract information from a variety of videos. So far, I have tested it with AVI, FLV, MP4, and 3GP videos and have managed to successfully obtain information about each video using the PHP script below.

```
<?php
$ffmpegInstance = new ffmpeg_movie("http://localhost/ffmpeg/movie");
$frame_count = $ffmpegInstance->getFrameCount();
$frame = $ffmpegInstance->getFrame(round($frame_count / 2));
?>
```

The problem is that when I run the PHP script, I keep lotting lots of xdebug warnings and notices. For example, when I am using a 3GP video, I get the following notice;

**Notice: ffmpeg_movie::__construct() []: ISO: File Type Major Brand: 3gp4 - line 2**

When I am using a FLV video, I get this notice repeated 35 times for the same line in the PHP file;

**Notice: ffmpeg_movie::__construct() []: Unsupported video codec (7) - line 2**

When I am using a MP4 video, I get these warnings repeated multiple times;

**Notice: ffmpeg_movie::__construct() []: ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom - line 2**

**Warning: ffmpeg_movie::getframe() []: abs_diff_pic_num overflow - line 4**

**Warning: ffmpeg_movie::getframe() []: decode_slice_header error - line 4**

**Notice: ffmpeg_movie::getframe() []: concealing 99 DC, 99 AC, 99 MV errors - line 4**

And when I use an AVI video, I get these warnings repeated multiple times;

**Warning: ffmpeg_movie::getframe() []: abs_diff_pic_num overflow - line 4**

**Warning: ffmpeg_movie::getframe() []: decode_slice_header error - line 4**

**Notice: ffmpeg_movie::getframe() []: concealing 99 DC, 99 AC, 99 MV errors - line 4**

I am relatively new to using FFmpeg-PHP and I do not understand what these messages mean, why they are appearing, or how I can improve my coding to get rid of them. I have done as much research as I can, and so far I cannot find any answers to why these errors are appearing or any solutions to these errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are mostly warnings (and notices) that ffmpeg-php delegates from the library to PHP land. This is called "noisy". The ffmpeg extension shouldn't do this, but instead collect all those errors and warnings so that you can retrieve them if you're interested. From what I can see, none of the warnings and notices you get here are important and are an artifact of all the different video encoders.

cheers
Derick

Comment: If you are concerned about the warnings and notices, you can just use error_reporting(0) in your code, to hide them.